# can i implement `_exit`c function in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I want to consume c obj files in delphi xe3.

When linked obj files, shows this error:

```
`[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(149): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_exit'`
```

can i implement `_exit` function?

Comment: What about doing: `procdure _exit(const Status: Integer); cdecl;
  external 'msvcrt.dll' name 'exit';` Be aware that there are `_exit()`, `exit()` and `_Exit()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can indeed do this. Typically you will link the .obj file to a single unit in your project. Implement the `exit` function in that unit and the Delphi linker will find it.

```
....

implementation

....

{$LINK foo.obj}

procedure _exit(status: Integer); cdecl;
begin
  // your implementation goes here
end;
```

As I've illustrated this you place the function in the implementation section of the unit. It does not need to be visible externally to the unit.

You might have multiple different units that link to C objects, in which case you can place your C runtime functions, like `exit`, in a single unit, and use that from each other unit that links to C objects. In that scenario then you need to expose each function in the interface section so that the linker can see the function.